# display welcome messsage on browser using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here i am trying to print message "Welcome from spring - mvc" on browser. But its not getting printed.
Here is my controller class which handles the request.

```
package org.spring.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome from spring - mvc");

        return "welcome";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/helloAgain",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHelloAgain(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome again from spring - mvc");

        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Here is the welcome.jsp, a view to be displayed.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> <title>Helloworldxmlspring</title>
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Welcome to Spring MVC</h1> 
<h3>${message}</h3>
<h2>hiiiiiiiiiii..</h2> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>HelloWorldxml</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>

            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatch-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my bean configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.spring.controller.HelloWorldController"/>


<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

<property name="prefix">
<value>/WEB-INF/views/</value></property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Its printing

> Welcome to spring MVC and hiiiiiiiiiii..

But the model data sent by `servlet`. i.e {message} is not printing. what is the reason?

Comment: Is your program-flow reaching `sayHelloAgain` method? You can check that by debugging the program.

Comment: i dont now how to debug...the controller is working fine..even the heading tag in welcome.jsp is working. but the value sen by the servlet is not printing. ie.{$message}

Comment: I doubt your flow is reaching your `sayHelloAgain` method. It is always hitting the first method `sayHello`. You can learn how to debug using debugger, it will be very useful in your programming journey. Using ***log4j*** is also nice option. As of now you can place a **sysout** statement in both the function to know which method is executed.

Comment: Thank you dhaval..i am not invoking the sayHelloAgain().. i am trying on first method only..but i am not able to display the message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView sayHello(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome from spring - mvc");
    return new ModelAndView("welcome");
}
@RequestMapping(value="/helloAgain",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView sayHelloAgain(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome again from spring - mvc");
    return new ModelAndView("welcome");
}
```

In Spring framework`org.springframework.ui.Model` is primarily designed for adding attributes to the model. Allows for accessing the overall model as a `java.util.Map`. Model attribute is used as a data/information transfer barrier in spring web application.

`org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` is a holder for both Model and View in the web MVC framework.This class merely holds both to make it possible for a controller to return both model and view in a single return value.

So it is always best practice to use `return new ModelAndView("welcome");` or `return new ModelAndView("welcome","DATA",model);` and pass the view name in controller. Because `return "welcome";` may sometimes fail to add Model data in View.

Comment: my pleasure. you can rate my answer.

Comment: @BirajSahoo You should also add some brief explanation as to why above changes should be made or how above changes will bring the required output. This will help others not only solve current issue but also avoid similar issues in future.

Comment: @DhavalSimaria. I have added few description to my answer with use of Model and ModelAndView in Spring MVC. Hope you find it helpful. Thanks for reminding me to add description to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Model not ModelMap, ModelMap contains information for model only.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/helloAgain",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String sayHelloAgain(Model model){
model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome again from spring - mvc");

return "welcome";
}
```

Do this for all your controller API's which need to access view.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but is saying The method addAttribute(String, String) is undefined for the type ModelAndView..why?

Comment: hello bro, i am not able to print that.  even i tried like this.                                                                   @Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView sayHello(ModelAndView model){
  model.setViewName("welcome");
 
  model.addObject("message", "Welcome from spring - mvc");
 
  
  return model;
 }

Comment: Nope...nothing is happening Amer. please rectify it.